# openssl_dh_compute_key(): Argument #2 ($private_key) must be of type OpenSSLAsymmetricKey

Tags: php, encryption, diffie-hellman

I am trying to decrypt a response Tokens which where encrypted using a Diffie-Hellman (type curve25519) via AES-GCM and additional authenticated data (AAD). I am new to PHP so I am not sure how can this be accomplished.

here is my attempt:

```php
<?php


$private_key =  openssl_pkey_get_private("file:///vault-sink/private");

$pub_key_struct =  file_get_contents("/vault-sink/public");
$json_public_key = json_decode($pub_key_struct);


$secret = openssl_dh_compute_key($json_public_key->curve25519_public_key, $private_key);

$token_response =  file_get_contents("/vault-sink/token.txt");
$token_response_json = json_decode($token_response);

echo $token_response_json->encrypted_payload;

openssl_decrypt(
    $secret,
    $token_response_json->encrypted_payload,
    $token_response_json->nonce,
    $aad = "test"
);
```

**error**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: openssl_dh_compute_key(): Argument #2 ($private_key) must be of type OpenSSLAsymmetricKey, bool given in /vault-sink/php-client/main.php:10
```

content of public and private keys:

```sh
# cat public
{"curve25519_public_key":"ru7+Ncx9x8Y/pHlj3D/wg+WYCQgqMKuVpAmTjCmf7Hs="}

# cat private
9fd06c52f7fda2b89bb05ac591dbeba8e57984c2bb0e6181ddcf275fb87015b6
```

So my guess is that the private's key format is not readable by `openssl_pkey_get_private` function. My question is how can I use these private and public keys in `openssl_dh_compute_key`?

For more context, below is an example on how I did it with go.

---

### Working example with Go

#### Generate KeyPair

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    dh "github.com/hashicorp/vault/helper/dhutil"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }
}

func generatePublicPrivateKey() {

    var keyinfo dh.PublicKeyInfo

    public, private, err := dh.GeneratePublicPrivateKey()
    check(err)

    keyinfo.Curve25519PublicKey = public
    pubkey, err := json.Marshal(keyinfo)
    check(err)

    err = os.WriteFile("public", []byte(pubkey), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    privateKey := fmt.Sprintf("%x", private)

    err = os.WriteFile("private", []byte(privateKey), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    generatePublicPrivateKey()
}
```

output

```sh
# cat public
{"curve25519_public_key":"ru7+Ncx9x8Y/pHlj3D/wg+WYCQgqMKuVpAmTjCmf7Hs="}

# cat private
9fd06c52f7fda2b89bb05ac591dbeba8e57984c2bb0e6181ddcf275fb87015b6
```

#### Encrypt Token Using Hashicorp Vault

then I run Vault Agent and get the following response ("token.txt"):

```json
{
    "curve25519_public_key": "ONwU5iknsVP57p7PdHtN4rzxbivMB4Bt5o2BJFC6oSc=",
    "nonce": "AA2VibL5SXE9MU19",
    "encrypted_payload": "pPseQIue1IXxutEKoZrjsORj+8AZVgRrcTRvaPVxukzU2w28TL4T0be7aGFKZmHwudiHiNQyp5i8D0ZUgP/ILLYPfhO+gwxUFEDhA4PJNAgKc8nSaMpjG9RipAyRcepgk42SXuRIgZ1D7HrmeWT8"
}
```

for more info, check https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/agent/autoauth#encrypting-tokens

#### Decrypt the token

and then I decrypt the response as following

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    dh "github.com/hashicorp/vault/helper/dhutil"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }
}

func main() {

    var envelope dh.Envelope
    var keyinfo dh.PublicKeyInfo

    token_env, err := os.ReadFile("token.txt")
    check(err)

    err = json.Unmarshal(token_env, &envelope)
    check(err)

    ourPublic, err := os.ReadFile("public")
    check(err)

    ourPrivate, err := os.ReadFile("private")
    check(err)

    json.Unmarshal(ourPublic, &keyinfo)

    privatekey, err := hex.DecodeString(string(ourPrivate))
    check(err)

    secret, err := dh.GenerateSharedSecret(privatekey, envelope.Curve25519PublicKey)
    check(err)

    shared_key, err := dh.DeriveSharedKey(secret, keyinfo.Curve25519PublicKey, envelope.Curve25519PublicKey)
    check(err)

    test, err := dh.DecryptAES(shared_key, envelope.EncryptedPayload, envelope.Nonce, []byte("test"))
    check(err)

    fmt.Println(string(test))
}
```

output

```sh
hvs.CAESIB1eP79cHXPc4ttZIz20qL2I2A8kcfNpkhPjvIE4DZt3Gh4KHGh2cy4wNWV1WHB5NWNuZXV1dDMzdkh4YkY2OUE
```

Comment: [`openssl_pkey_get_private()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private) expects a PEM-formatted private key, not whatever that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shared secret can be determined in PHP with the [Sodium](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sodium.php) library and the [`sodium_crypto_scalarmult()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sodium-crypto-scalarmult.php) function.

For the calculation of the shared key the Go source code of [`DeriveSharedKey()`](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/main/helper/dhutil/dhutil.go#L56) shows that the shared key is derived with [HKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HKDF) (see [*hkdf.go*](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/hkdf#New)) and the two public keys are sorted and used as *salt* and *info*. For this purpose [`hash_hkdf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hkdf.php) can be used on the PHP side.

Finally, decryption takes place with AES-256 in GCM mode, e.g. with [`openssl_encrypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php). In contrast to the Go code, where ciphertext and tag are concatenated, `openssl_encrypt()` handles both separately.

The resulting PHP code is (for simplicity, the input data is assigned directly, i.e. without file I/O):

```php
// Input data
$payload = base64_decode("pPseQIue1IXxutEKoZrjsORj+8AZVgRrcTRvaPVxukzU2w28TL4T0be7aGFKZmHwudiHiNQyp5i8D0ZUgP/ILLYPfhO+gwxUFEDhA4PJNAgKc8nSaMpjG9RipAyRcepgk42SXuRIgZ1D7HrmeWT8");
$nonce = base64_decode("AA2VibL5SXE9MU19");
$ourPublicKey = base64_decode("ru7+Ncx9x8Y/pHlj3D/wg+WYCQgqMKuVpAmTjCmf7Hs=");
$theirPublicKey = base64_decode("ONwU5iknsVP57p7PdHtN4rzxbivMB4Bt5o2BJFC6oSc=");
$privateKey = hex2bin("9fd06c52f7fda2b89bb05ac591dbeba8e57984c2bb0e6181ddcf275fb87015b6");

// Get shared secret
$sharedSecret = sodium_crypto_scalarmult($privateKey, $theirPublicKey);
print("Shared secret (hex): " . sodium_bin2hex($sharedSecret) . PHP_EOL); // Shared secret (hex): 48cb642fe6ecd7e4ff4a58610524f873e8ab86b8ccb195f0c90d59c477d6f437

// Get shared key
// Go:  hkdf.New(hash, secret, salt, info)
// PHP: hash_hkdf($algo, $key, $length, $info, $salt)
if (strcmp($ourPublicKey, $theirPublicKey) == -1) {
    $salt = $ourPublicKey;
    $info = $theirPublicKey;
} else { // for simplicity the 0 case is not considered dedicated, the Go code throws an exception here
    $salt = $theirPublicKey;
    $info = $ourPublicKey;
}
$sharedKey = hash_hkdf("sha256", $sharedSecret, 32, $info, $salt);
print("Shared key (hex): " . bin2hex($sharedKey) . PHP_EOL); // Shared key (hex): cacbda4874426b1208903d24378bdc0fb7a7dd08c91b5f275c11ff39e58add38

// Decrypt with AES-256, GCM
$ciphertext = substr($payload, 0, strlen($payload) - 16);
$tag = substr($payload, strlen($payload) - 16, 16);
$aad = "test";
$plaintext = openssl_encrypt($ciphertext, "aes-256-gcm", $sharedKey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $nonce, $tag, $aad);
print("Plaintext: " . $plaintext . PHP_EOL); // Plaintext: hvs.CAESIB1eP79cHXPc4ttZIz20qL2I2A8kcfNpkhPjvIE4DZt3Gh4KHGh2cy4wNWV1WHB5NWNuZXV1dDMzdkh4YkY2OUE
```

with the same output as the Go code.